# Use different versions of paging library in the same project

Tags: android, paging, android-paging, android-paging-3

How can I use paging 2 in one module and paging 3 in another module? Now I have paging 3 dependencies pulled into both modules

Comment: Paging 3 didn't _delete_ any Paging 2 APIs, they're still all there for you to use. What makes you think you can't use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the module connection where I used paging 3, I used this code:

```
exclude(group = "androidx.paging", module = "paging-runtime")
exclude(group = "androidx.paging", module = "paging-compose")
```